# Getter and setter problems

Tags: java, return, setter, getter

I am new here and new in Java. I have an assignment in Java and this is the question:

The class should have the following methods:

1. A constructor without arguments that initializes the name to "unknown", the urea and protein levels to 0.0 and the bleedingHistory value to false.
2. A constructor that receives arguments for name and bleeding history and initializes the urea level and protein level to 0.0.
3. Getters for all the instance variables
4. Setters for all the instance variables, with validation for the
   following:

   - name cannot be blank
   - urea level must be between 0 and 10, inclusive
   - protein level must be between 0 and 150, inclusive

If any of the values passed in to the setters are invalid, then do not change the value of the instance variable and return false.

This is the instances variable:

```
public class Patient {

    private String name;
    private boolean bleedingHistory = true;

    private double ureaLevel;
    private double proLevel;
```

So my question is how to return to the instance variable above if the input value is not correct.

Comment: For a start you will need to declare your fields outside of the constructor otherwise they will only be visible to the constructor

Comment: To start with, those aren't instance variables, instance variables need to be defined at the class level.  Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Also, if the value passed to the getter is invalid, you shouldn't be modifying the instance fields any way, so there shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: oh sorry posted the wrong part.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  so what you mean is the getter part i will not need to return anything?

Comment: @NoahSkullWeijian The getters will return the value of the instance field, they want need to care about if the value is valid or not, because the setters should have guarded against invalid values

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, just make sure your setters have if-statements in them that validate the input. If the validation fails, don't change the variable at all; instead, throw an IllegalArgumentException to let the caller know that the name was unchanged. (Credit: @ADTC)

For example, here is the setter for the patient's name:

```
public void setName(String newName)  throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(newName != null && !newName.isEmpty()) 
    {
        this.name = newName;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

What the if-statement is evaluating is: "if `newName` is **not** `null`, **and** `newName` is **not** empty, then we will replace `this.name` with `newName`. Otherwise, we will throw a `new IllegalArgumentException()`."

Notice how if the if-statement evaluates to `true`, the variable `name` is replaced with `newName`, however, if it evaluates to `false`, we throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. If you were to call this method in your code, it should be called inside of a try-catch statement, like so:

```
try
{
    setName("John Doe");
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
    //Name was not changed. Either it was null, or it was empty.
}
```

Comment: Actually the setter should throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when validation fails, so that the caller can know of the validation status. Otherwise the program will continue on with the assumption that the value has been set, when it actually has not.

Comment: @ADTC Great point! I'll see if I can work that into my answer

Comment: If you wanted to get all OCD then you could also check that the passed in param does not already match what is in the class variable. IE. if it is the same don't change it. Some thing like..
... && n    if(newName != null && !newName.isEmpty() && !newName.equals(name)) {

Comment: @JacquesRamsden you're right, and that might be something I would do too, but his assignment says only to check if it is empty, so that's all I put in.

Comment: @Mitch Talmadge 100% in agreement . :D